# MongoDB MMS identify database write heavy or read heavy

Tags: mongodb, mms

By referring to MongoDB MMS, is there a way to identify whether a database is designed for write-heavy use case or read-heavy use case?

Example of a database I'm monitoring:
[image: mms]

Comment: Your question isn't [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as a programming question for StackOverflow. General operations/performance questions would be better suited to ServerFault, but you need something more specific than a screenshot. For example, if there was a specific performance problem you would look into what operations or resources might be limiting performance and ask for advice on tuning (eg. how to better index a slow query).

Comment: Whether your server configuration will suit your expected read or write workload really depends on the *actual* workload and schema design. Useful preso to watch: [William Zola - The (Only) Three Reasons for Slow MongoDB Performance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJFXM6tZJqg).